# How to change shortcode's default theme?

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I'm very new to web development. I'm currently using Divi to build my page and I'm using predefined shortcodes like [submit_job_form] of WP Job Manager plugin. When I add this to my page, the appearance of the shortcode module (the form it populates) is rudimentary. The page's theme does not apply to it.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could build a child theme that would apply custom CSS you develop to style the form more like the rest of the site. Or, some themes have a custom CSS area where you can paste in your styles without having to build a child theme. Either way, it will take some custom CSS.

Answer (score 1):

WP Job Manager also has documentation on customizing the forms. See https://wpjobmanager.com/document/adding-custom-css-for-wp-job-manager/